# Prerequisites on installing Spidermonkey

Tags: spidermonkey

Considering there is no Mozilla related engines installed on a linux machine. What are the specific libraries or engines needed to successfully install Spidermonkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having built Spidermonkey myself some time ago, I think there are actually no dependencies other than the standard clib and some posix stuff for things like the JS URI Objects.

There's the [Mozilla Linux Build Prerequisites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Linux_Build_Prerequisites), if you want to build it as part of the mozilla tree, although the actual dependencies of Spidermonkey are considerably less.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be part of a Mozilla. I am working on a very resource-limited machine thats why I want to know what are the needed libraries to be able to compile Spidermonkey to become a library. I want to make a C application that uses Spidermonkey for its Javascript capability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it needs to be part of a Mozilla. I am working on a very resource-limited machine thats why I want to know what are the needed libraries to be able to compile Spidermonkey to become a library. I want to make a C application that uses Spidermonkey for its Javascript capability.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine runs Ubuntu you can try using the Spidermonkey package from Launchpad Developers PPA. You can check the package build dependencies for such list.

```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:launchpad/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install spidermonkey-bin
```